# Recent file in Macbook Air

Tags: mac

I am not a very techie girl. I used my brother's macbook air and saw some of his personal things which I should haven't. And I realised that he could see that in recents. How to delete them?
After surfing a lot, I got to know about the recent files stored in plist in preferences, by the name com.apple.recentfiles.plist or LSSharedfiles.plist but I couldn't find a file/plist named above. Kindly help!
As mentioned above it is macbook air and again I do not know much :(

Comment: Please do not close my question rather tell me in the comment what's wrong. It would be great if I get some help!

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is, there isn't just one store of recent files, there's one for every app - see [Ask Different - Remove recent documents history?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33446/remove-recent-documents-history/144601)

There is one method not mentioned there* which will clear everything - however, by everything I do mean that, all recents from all apps, optionally also clearing the entire browser history & cache.
This will mean that, though no-one will be able to see where you went or what you opened, it will be really really obvious someone wiped the history.

This is one of those occasions where, though no-one will know what you're guilty ***of***, it will be perfectly obvious you're guilty of … ***something***.

[Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html), freeware [make sure you download the correct version for your OS] can do this & many other tasks. It's not 'dangerous' to use, ie it will not break anything, but it will make it very obvious that the histories have been cleaned.

The main file history is on the main screen -

[image]

and the browser data is in the Options button to the right

[image]

*It's mentioned now, I just added it.

Comment: May I please know what will happen if I click on recent items?
Like will it delete all the recent items or a particular one which I visited by mistake?
Apologies for my noobness :)

Comment: It's basically a picture which I saw of his, so basically I want to remove that particular picture from recents in doc without deleting the picture!