# How to Use OnyX?

Tags: macbook-air

I recently got to know about OnyX to delete recent history on docs. How shall I use it?
Will clicking on recent items delete all the recent items on doc or a particular recent item which I visited today?
Please refer [Recent file in Macbook Air](https://superuser.com/questions/1637571/recent-file-in-macbook-air) for the image, I am talking about the "recent items" mentioned in the 1st picture?

Comment: I'm pretty certain this was already answered quite clearly in the linked question  [Recent file in Macbook Air](https://superuser.com/questions/1637571/recent-file-in-macbook-air)

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't really understand it, Can you please answer the comment which I made in the linked question?

Comment: What part of "will clear everything - however, by everything I do mean that, all recents from all apps, optionally also clearing the entire browser history & cache." isn't clear?

Comment: When you open doc you have finder you have "recents" where you can view the recent files you visited on mac. So basically I saw a picture of his which is now shown in recents in that finder, I want to delete "only" that particular picture from the "recents". I hope I am clear :)

Comment: Yes. This is reasonably clear. My answer to your first question linked to several potential solutions plus one additional 'wipe everything' option.